# EADDRINUSE error Node.js - Netstat doesn't show the port being used

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to run a basic express backend on my local machine on port 3000, but I keep getting the EADDRINUSE error.

In the past, I just solved this problem with
netstat -ano | findStr :3000
and taskkill /pid  /f

Now, when I run the netstat command, I don't see any active task ids. I also checked the total task list with the general find-all command and also checked task manager to kill node.exe but that wasn't there either.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

I've tried restarting the computer multiple times already. SL3 if that helps.

ty

Comment: try `netstat -pant`

Comment: lol tried that ty I ended up figuring out the problm i had a socket.io function call creating a server on the same port.

Comment: that will do it, btw you can use the same server instance for both express and socket.io, dont need multi ports

Comment: yeayea ty  i have const server  = app.listen(port, ........) and io = require()(server)